# Расчет суммы значения с 10 числа прошлого прошлого месяца по 10 число следующего месяца

Tags: phpmyadmin

Всем привет!

```
$val = 0;   
if(date("Ymd", strtotime("tenth day of last month") )>= date('Ymd', strtotime($value['time'])) && date("Ymd", strtotime("tenth day of this month") ) <= date('Ymd', strtotime($value['time'])))         
    $val += $value['money'];
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо формата "Ymd" попробуйте "U" в функции date().
Это конвертнет все даты в число секунд, с 1970 года, и правильно их сравнит.